# how to create a fixed/sticky header on scroll with React

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to create a fixed/sticky header on the scroll in React.

But I am unable to create this stuff. I am giving a reference to design what I want to do.

(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header)
I want to implement the following in react

````
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```</script>
````

Comment: It doesn't appear you are using react in this code, do you have it set up already?

Comment: this is not react code but I want implement it in react. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header

Comment: Could you share your html with us as well?

Comment: here is the code: (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using the position css property. `position: sticky; top:0px;`.  Note browser comparability.